# How does variable scoping work in a POE session?

Tags: perl, session-state, scope, poe

Can anyone explain how variable scoping works within a POE session? What is the proper way to pass state within the session, without impacting other sessions?

Thanks
Josh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scoping is unaffected by POE.

You can use POE's heap (accessible through `$_[HEAP]`) to pass data around between your various handlers.

[According to the docs](http://search.cpan.org/dist/POE/lib/POE/Session.pm#%24_%5bHEAP%5d), the heap is distinct between sessions by default, but it is possible to override this so that different sessions share a heap.

```
sub my_state_handler {
    $_[HEAP]{some_data} = 'foo';
    $_[KERNEL]->yield('another_handler');
}

sub another_handler {
    print $_[HEAP]{some_data}, "\n"; # prints "foo\n"
}
```

Comment: When creating a session, a new hash is used for the heap, as you said. One can specify the heap manually when creating a session: http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?POE::Session#heap_=>_ANYTHING

You could use an existing hash for session's heap, or an array, etc.